# Loader fails without a complete event

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm trying to get a loader working in a flex web application, but it isn't responding to the complete event. Is there a change I should make to the code here, or some way that I can handle an error event to get more information?

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.cacheAsBitmap = true;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("logo.png");
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void
{
    //use the image here
});
loader.load(request);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're declaring your eventListener inline like that instead of referencing a separate function? You may also want to try `loader.load(new URLRequest("logo.png"));`

Comment: @Jason Towne - I'm using a closure to pass on the image and a few other variables to another function - changing that doesn't make it work. The request is broken out into it's own variable so that I could more easily be sure it's properties were set correctly - in my app, the string is read (successfully) from a config file.

Comment: Are you sure the `addEventListener` function is getting called? Perhaps the eventListener isn't getting added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed the contentLoaderInfo!The code should say

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void
```

Comment: Bingo. Any `Loader` requires the `contentLoaderInfo` for its listeners since it's a `DisplayObject`. Conversely, a `URLLoader` does not since it's not a `DisplayObject`.